# Move pre-rendered tiles to other machine

Tags: mod-tile

I have server and PC with same settings and dataset with renderd and mod_tile. Which files I must copy when I want use pre-rendered tiles from PC to server?

Because when I copy /var/cache/renderd/tiles/s2o/, it is re-rendered when I use it by apache2.